# Hibernate and MYSQL: You have an error in your SQL syntax?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, mysql-error-1064

I have the following query in my java code:

```
String queryString = "select \r\n" +
        "cms.status_id as 'statusId',\r\n" +
        "cms.status_label as 'statusLabel',\r\n" +
        "csl.status as 'status',\r\n" +
        "from "+client+".my_status cms \r\n" +
        "join "+client+".status_list csl on csl.status = cms.status_id\r\n";
```

When I run the code I get the following error:

```
SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax
```

What could be causing this? I cannot seen an issue with my query and manually I am able to get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra comma in this line:

```
 "csl.status as 'status',\r\n" +
```